# layer.presentationLayer frame not returning proper display frame during UIView animation

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview

I've been trying to get hold of the frame of an object as displayed during a UIView animation. Reason being, I have a couple of UI elements that I want to update stuff with that depends on their position on the screen.

I know that the view's frame property returns its destination frame once the animation is triggered so I've been trying to get the frame of its presentation layer. For example, a view contains a subview called `handle`. The view animates `handle` from its current position using:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1 animations:^{
    self.handle.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
}];
```

`handle` has a timer that reports its current frame using:

```
NSLog(@"frame: %@", [NSValue valueWithCGRect:[self.layer.presentationLayer frame]]);
```

I've tried variations on getting the presentationLayer frame including:

```
((CALayer *)self.layer.presentationLayer).frame
```

I've tried having the timer in the outer view reporting the frame of `handle`:

```
[self.handle.layer.presentationLayer frame]
```

I've tried animating with different variations on `[UIView animateWithDuration...`. I've tried animating using by setting up a `CABasicAnimation` and `[UIView beginAnimations ... commitAnimations]`.

I've tried on iPad2, iPad Mini, and the simulator, all with the same problem.

In all cases it reports a steady stream of identical CGRects. The animations always happen without any other issue. I've got Quartz imported on both the superview and `handle`.

I feel I've exhausted as many posts etc on this topic as I can find. I feel that all of this should work, and other people seem to of had success with it, so what might get in the way of this working?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Those are many of the steps and checks I would have taken and made. Are you certain that the timer is running often enough to catch the one second animation? You could conceivably set up a KVO method to watch `self.handle.layer.presentationlayer.frame`. This sounds silly, but are you sure that `self.handle.frame != CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)` at the start of your animation?

Comment: It's definitely running fast enough, it spits out the wrong and constant frame through the animation duration. I've tried a KVO, but couldn't get it set up to observe the presentationlayer's frame. In any case, the timer reports a constant frame for the presentation layer. And the handle's definitely moving through the animation. Hmm...